# C# SQL Server Finding Optimal MinPoolSize Setting

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

I would like to keep a min number of connections alive in the pool for performance reasons.

The DB is read only and exposed via a stateless WCF service, so I think setting MinPoolSize from a default of 0 makes sense in this scenario.

At the same time I don't want to set the value too high unnecessarily wasting memory by keeping a large number of idle connections.

What would be the best practice or recommended setting a custom MinPoolSize in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum number of connections in a connection pool cannot be less than two

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. However I'm curious as to what is the optimal number to keep alive.